# PHP - Calculate as per daily weekly and monthly basis based on fixed prices

Tags: php, datediff, price

I have an issue on calculating the Daily, Weekly, and Monthly rates for my rental products.

**310 Daily / 725 Weekly /1,660 Monthly**

When comes to logic :

*Day 1 + day 2 = 620* but *Day 1 + day 2 + day 3 = 930* which is greater than 725 (Weekly). So here week price should be applied till it reaches 7 days.

Now,
*Day 8 = Day 7 + 310 =1035 (Not > 1660 MONTHLY RENT)* 
*Day 9 = Day 8 + 310 =1345 (Not > 1660 MONTHLY RENT)* 
*Day 10 = Day 9 + 310 =**1655** (Not > 1660 MONTHLY RENT)* but, it is greater than 2 weeks price and days are less than 14.
So here it should apply 725+725=1450 till 14 days.

**....**

**....**

**Day 14 = 1450**

Now,
*Day 15 = Day 14 +310 = **1760** ( > 1660 )* 
Here, it should apply 1660 till the end of the month.

**....**

**....**

**Day 30/31 = 1660**

I tried a lot to build but not successful. Can any one help me out here.

**Updated code :**

```
<?php

$perDayAmt=310;
$perWeekAmt=725;
$perMonthAmt=1660;

$finalAmt=0;
$start_date=new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));//, strtotime("+12 days")
$end_date=new DateTime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+14 days")));

$differenceInDays = $end_date->diff($start_date)->format("%a");
if($differenceInDays >0){

if($differenceInDays <= 7){
    if(($differenceInDays*$perDayAmt) <= $perWeekAmt){// 5 days amount <= $perWeekAmt amount
        $finalAmt = $differenceInDays*$perDayAmt; //no. of days * $perDayAmt amount
    }else{
        $finalAmt =$perWeekAmt; // $perWeekAmt amount
    }
}else{
    /*if( ($differenceInDays%7) == 0 && ($perWeekAmt*($differenceInDays/7)) < $perMonthAmt){
        //14 < 30 && 14 % 7==0 && $perWeekAmt amount * [2 or 3 or 4 or 5] < $perMonthAmt amount
        $finalAmt = $perWeekAmt*($differenceInDays/7); //$perWeekAmt amount * [2 or 3 or 4 or 5]
    }else if(($differenceInDays%7) != 0 && ($perWeekAmt*($differenceInDays/7)) < $perMonthAmt){
        //10 < 30 &&  10 % 7!=0 && 10 days amount > $perWeekAmt amount
        $finalAmt =$perWeekAmt; // $perWeekAmt amount
    }*/
    if( ($differenceInDays%7) == 0) {
        if(($perWeekAmt*($differenceInDays/7)) > $perMonthAmt){
            if( ($differenceInDays%30) == 0) {
                $finalAmt = $perMonthAmt*($differenceInDays/30);
            }else{

            }

        }else if(($perWeekAmt*($differenceInDays/7)) < $perMonthAmt){
            $finalAmt = $perWeekAmt*($differenceInDays/7);
        }
    }
}

echo $finalAmt;exit;    
}
```

Here is the reference link you can add a product to cart:

https://www.zieglerrental.com/equipment/skid-steer-compact-loaders/cat-compact-track-loaders/cat-239d-compact-track-loader/

Comment: What have you tried and how was it not successful?

Comment: Please add your logic here in a code.

Comment: is a month 28, 29, 30 or 31 days? When does it become "one month plus one day"?

Comment: ya, one month +one day will again start with same scenario. Top down approach

Comment: That is not an answer to my question

Comment: As asked, I have updated the code here up to the extent I have tried.

Comment: here they can select the month/year range limit what ever they want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than writing a block of `if` or `switch-case` statements, using `min()` with three variables will concisely perform this task.  See the verbose output from my demo snippet below for the three values being compared for each `$diff` occurrence.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e59d8f4dc1e581d0db5bab304bf647cc212647bc))

```
$pricing=['day'=>310,'week'=>725,'month'=>1660];
for($x=0; $x<33; ++$x){
    echo "$x : ";
    $finalAmt=0;
    $start_date=new DateTime('today');
    $end_date=new DateTime(date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+$x days")));

    $diff=$end_date->diff($start_date);

    if($diff->y){$finalAmt+=$diff->y*12*$pricing['month'];}

    if($diff->m){$finalAmt+=$diff->m*$pricing['month'];}

    if($diff->d){
        $weeks=floor($diff->d/7);
        $days=$diff->d%7;
        $raw=$weeks*$pricing['week']+$days*$pricing['day'];
        $weekup=$pricing['week']*($weeks+1);
        $finalAmt+=min($raw,$weekup,$pricing['month']);  // <-- here is the magic; min() on three variables
    }
    echo "\$$finalAmt";
    if($diff->d){echo " is min of: $raw & $weekup & {$pricing['month']}";}
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
0 : $0
1 : $310 is min of: 310 & 725 & 1660
2 : $620 is min of: 620 & 725 & 1660
3 : $725 is min of: 930 & 725 & 1660
4 : $725 is min of: 1240 & 725 & 1660
5 : $725 is min of: 1550 & 725 & 1660
6 : $725 is min of: 1860 & 725 & 1660
7 : $725 is min of: 725 & 1450 & 1660
8 : $1035 is min of: 1035 & 1450 & 1660
9 : $1345 is min of: 1345 & 1450 & 1660
10 : $1450 is min of: 1655 & 1450 & 1660
11 : $1450 is min of: 1965 & 1450 & 1660
12 : $1450 is min of: 2275 & 1450 & 1660
13 : $1450 is min of: 2585 & 1450 & 1660
14 : $1450 is min of: 1450 & 2175 & 1660
15 : $1660 is min of: 1760 & 2175 & 1660
16 : $1660 is min of: 2070 & 2175 & 1660
17 : $1660 is min of: 2380 & 2175 & 1660
18 : $1660 is min of: 2690 & 2175 & 1660
19 : $1660 is min of: 3000 & 2175 & 1660
20 : $1660 is min of: 3310 & 2175 & 1660
21 : $1660 is min of: 2175 & 2900 & 1660
22 : $1660 is min of: 2485 & 2900 & 1660
23 : $1660 is min of: 2795 & 2900 & 1660
24 : $1660 is min of: 3105 & 2900 & 1660
25 : $1660 is min of: 3415 & 2900 & 1660
26 : $1660 is min of: 3725 & 2900 & 1660
27 : $1660 is min of: 4035 & 2900 & 1660
28 : $1660 is min of: 2900 & 3625 & 1660
29 : $1660 is min of: 3210 & 3625 & 1660
30 : $1660 is min of: 3520 & 3625 & 1660
31 : $1660
32 : $1970 is min of: 310 & 725 & 1660
```

Comment: Excellent. Man you really saved my another day of try. Thanks a lot. Have a great day  :).